# E-mail sending JS SMTP

Tags: javascript, html, forms, smtp

firstly it's sending emails and it's work properly but the problem is with '*Body*'. It's doesn't take values from inputs.
The sended message look like this:

Name:
Email:
Message:
Example from html:

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="First Name"><br>
```

And js:

```
const nameInput = document.querySelector('#name');
const emailInput = document.querySelector('#email');
const messageInput = document.querySelector('#message');

       // Send email
    const sendEmail = () => {
        Email.send({
            Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
            Username: "email@gmail.com",
            Password: "email",
            To: 'email2@gmail.com',
            From: 'email@gmail.com',
            Subject: "New email from website",
            Body: "Name: " + nameInput.value + "<br>Email: " + emailInput.value + " <br>Message: " + messageInput.value
        }).then(
            message => alert(message)
        );
    }
```

What im doing wrong?

Comment: That looks like it should work. Are you remembering to type a value into the inputs before testing? Placeholders are not values.

Comment: [The  placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Yes I remember about that